# Debug a service in a network server from my computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, service

I'm installing my service in a server I have in the network.
But I want to debug it in there, because the behaviour is not going to be the same that in my computer. But I dont want to install Visual Studio again, pass the code, and debug from the server.
I want to do it from my computer.
I know how to do it if the service is in my machine, but not like this.
Anyone has fought this battle before?

Thank you

Comment: Remote debugging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thats what I tried, but I select the server (which I can see) and I'm connected to it but I can't see any service/process

Comment: You probably also have to set up the service to be "remote-debuggable". This might not be enabled by default because it's a massive security hole.

Comment: but is there a way to enable it only for my vpn?

Comment: No idea. The documentation has a section on remote debugging security: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242231(v=vs.100).aspx. Generally, it's probably a bad idea to have applications in production running in debug mode - get a proper test environment with snapshots of "real" data.